# unchecking checkbox in reactjs is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, filter, frontend

I made a todo app and I wanted to improvise it by showing all completed task if "Show completed task" is checked

[image]

Checking "Show completed task" works fine, but unchecking it doesn't execute the "else statement".
 
Originally what wanted is if its unchecked it should give me all the state, completed or not. 
The code from 'else statement' is just for debugging. It should at least give me the array[0] and array[2], tried console logging it, and it throws an undefined.

PS: tried to console log something upon unchecking, unchecked is working.

```
 filterCompleted  = (e) => {
    if(e.target.checked){
        this.setState({todos: [...this.state.todos.filter(todo => {return todo.completed === true})]})
    }
    else{
        //code below just for debugging but this does not execute
        this.setState({todos: [...this.state.todos.filter(todo => {return todo.completed === false})]})
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that you have to set a new array (for example todosToShow) and not reset the todos state variable, because after the first filtered you lost all values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will only ever work first time, beyond that the state will only ever hold all completed tasks or all uncompleted tasks.

You should introduce a new state e.g.

```
constructor(prop) {
  this.state = {
    todos: [],
    filterCompleted: false
  }
}
...
filterCompleted = e => this.setState({ filterCompleted: e.target.checked })
```

Then when rendering the list you can simply just exclude items that aren't `completed` e.g.

```
const items = this.state
  .todos
  .filter(x => !this.state.filterCompleted || x.completed)
  .map(x => <TodoItem {...x} />)
```

Comment: filterCompleted: false, without this code it still works

Comment: @DrewCordano yeah that's just being explicit with your default state, `undefined` is falsey though

Answer (score 1):

The Problem lies in the following line

```
    this.setState({todos: [...this.state.todos.filter(todo => {return todo.completed === true})]})
```

You are just filtering the items without channging them. You have to create a new array and set the value of the item to true/false. Something like this:

```
let newTodos = this.state.todos
newTodos[index].checked = true
this.setState({todos: newTodos})
```

index being some string/int that identifies the checkbox itself.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to leave the props and set a new state variable filterCompleted and during render filter all todoitems:

```
// when checked:
this.setState({ filterCompleted: true/false })

// during render (with hooks better with useMemo...):
todosToReder = this.state.filterCompleted ? this.state.todos.filter(el => el.completed) : this.state.todos
```